# Display only a single linked product category text on any page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I need to show different product categories on several regular pages but can't find a suitable shortcode for that.

Which shortcode do I have to use to show only single product category (without showing any products from that category) on any page?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you are asking is to get the link from a product category to display the linked product category name. For that you can build a custom shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('linked_pcat', 'display_a_linked_product_category');
function display_a_linked_product_category( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'term' => '',
    ), $atts, 'linked_pcat' );

    $taxomomy = 'product_cat';
    $value    = $atts['term'];

    if( is_numeric( $value ) || (string) (int) $value == $value ) {
        $field = 'term_id';
        $value = (int) $atts['term'];
    } else {
        $field = 'slug';
        $value = sanitize_title( $atts['term'] );
    }

    if( term_exists( $value, $taxomomy ) ) {
        $term      = get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxomomy );
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxomomy );

        return '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE:**

> ***Note:*** For the product category term can use a term name, a term slug or a term ID…

1) In the Wordpress Text Editor *(with a term name for example)*:

```
[linked_pcat term='Clothing']
```

2) Inside php code *(with a term slug for example)*:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[linked_pcat term='t-shirts']" );
```

3) In a php file between html code *(with a term Id for example)*:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[linked_pcat term='t-shirts']" ); ?>
```